# classList of combobox element returns undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components

How can I get the list of classes? my goal is to hide the combobox, so I want to add "slds-hidden" to the list of classes but when I print the value of startSelect I get undefined.

HTML:

```
<template if:false={isLoading}>
   <div class="slds-page-header slds-m-bottom_small">
      <div class="slds-grid">
         <div class="slds-col slds-has-flexi-truncate">
            <p class="slds-text-title_caps slds-line-height_reset">Mylist</p>
            <h1 class=>{myListTitle}</h1>
            <div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
               <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                  <div class="slds-col">
                     <lightning-combobox
                        name="mylist"
                        label="Mylist"
                        value={mylist}
                        data-id="mywl"
                        placeholder="Select"
                        options={mylistOptions}
                        onchange={handlemyListChange} 
                        ></lightning-combobox>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>

..
..
```

JS:

```
connectedCallback() {
    const startSelect = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="mywl"]').classList; //undefined
}
```

Comment: Try with: this.template.querySelector('[data-id="mywl"]').classList. If you use querySelectorAll you get back an array

Comment: not working, getting [Cannot read property 'classList' of null]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't query anything in the template in connectedCallback, because the component hasn't been rendered yet. If you query the records in an event handler (e.g. a button click), it should work fine. Also, it's rather normal to just use a conditional render instead of slds-hidden.

```
// Controller code
showCombobox;

<!-- Template markup -->
<lightning-combobox if:true={showCombobox}
```

There's no need to directly manipulate styles here.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, I have a follow-up question, I want to set a default value for this combobox, and I need it to be populated before I call the server side method (the default value will be used as a parameter for the apex method) - How can I do this without populating the value in the connectedCallback?

Comment: @Json Why do you want to avoid setting `mylist` in `connectedCallback`?

Comment: I need to check first who is the running user, and then per the running user I set the combobox to the appropriate value + calling the apex method to retrieve its related stuff

Comment: How are you calling the Apex? Is it a wired method, or imperative call?

Comment: imperative call

Comment: So, after you get the running user data, you can set the value in that callback handler instead of in connectedCallback. It'll just be blank before then, which should be okay, since it looks like you're not rendering the component while it's loading.